# How to select all rows containing $string in mysql_query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select every row where the field `show_meta` is equal to a string variable.

Right now, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `games` 
WHERE  `show_meta` =  'lost'
```

lost being the $string variable. Currently, this returns:

`MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0009 sec)`

Strangely, if I do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `games` 
WHERE  `tag` =  'action'
```

It does work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure that there are games that have `show_meta` as `lost` in the table?

Comment: Show your table structure.

Comment: @delmadord Yes, I made sure of that. There are more than 100 entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `games` 
WHERE  `show_meta` =  'lost'
```

This query will only return rows that are set EXACTLY to 'lost'. Probably no row is set exactly like that.

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `games` 
WHERE  `show_meta` LIKE '%lost%'
```

to select every row that has a word "lost" in `show meta`, where `%` means any string.